# Domain not persisted even after explicit save() when using read() to get it

Tags: grails

I retrieved the domain object using `read()`, changed some properties on it and explicitly saved it using `save()`. I can see version being updated but not properties

Properties should be updated along with the version as mentioned in grails `read()` documentation

Example Domain:

```
class AdhocChargeType{
    String adHocChargeType
    String glCode
}

Controller test method:

class AdhocChargeTypeController
{
    def testRead(Long id)
    {
        AdhocChargeType adHocChargeType = AdhocChargeType.read(id)
        adHocChargeType.properties = [adHocChargeType:"changed?"]
        adHocChargeType.save()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it save if you pass flush as true i.e `save(flush:true)`?

Comment: No. I doesn't update even with save(flush:true)

Comment: Can you include your version of grails and gorm-hibernate?

Comment: grails 3.1.12, gorm-hibernate4:5.0.13.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Grails save() method silently fails. If you have validation errors, then it will not save.

try with

*save flush:true, failOnError:true*

Resolve if there is any validation errors. The data should persist after that.

Comment: Checking return value of `save()` for non-null is generally a better idea than using `failOnError`.

Answer (score 0):

Upon saving a domain instance, Grails validates it using the defined constraints. The save will fail, if values in the domain instance violate those constraints. The problem is, this failure occurs quietly: you only know about it if you check the return value of save() or call hasErrors().

```
if (!adHocChargeType.save()) {
    // Save failed! Present the errors to the user.
    ...
}
```

Another approach is :

```
adHocChargeType.save(failOnError: true)
```

I suggest have a look into GORM best practices:

http://spring.io/blog/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/

http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/

http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/